# How to store an organization hierarchy in Active Directory and use it an app?

Tags: architecture, active-directory

As an example, let's say:

1. I have an organization call "USA". My users are "residents", and based on their primary address, each user typically have a city, county, and state, which are hierarchical by nature. But some users might have more or less levels depending on where they are: e.g. they might not have a city (just a county and state), or if living in a large city have a neighborhood in addition to the the city, county, and state. I don't know in advance how deep the hierarchy will be (e.g. neighborhoods might have further subdivisions). For each level in the hierarchy (neighborhood, city, county, and state), I have zero or more users who are "managers" for that city, county, or state.
2. Users access an app, with which they create artifacts. Artifacts are stored by the app in a separate database, say SQL Server. Users can access a particular artifact if they created it, or if they are one of the "managers" of the neighborhood, city, county, state, etc of the users who created the artifact.

(For simplicity, I'll just assume users never "move", i.e. the city, county, and state for a given user never changes throughout the life of the system.)

My questions are:

1. If users are defined in Active Directory, would you also store the organizational structure in Active Directory? And what about whether users are managers of what level? And if you would store this in Active Directory, how would you do it?
2. What information would you save along an artifact, so you can quickly get a list of all the artifacts a user has access to, without having to make a query to Active Directory for each artifact in the database?

For point 2, a possibility I envision would be to store in SQL Server, along with each artifact, the levels (city, county, state…) of the user who created it. This way a search could determine the levels the user is a manager of (`$levels_user_is_manager_of`) by making a query to Active Directory, and in the SQL query selecting which artifacts the user has access to do something like a `WHERE level in $levels_user_is_manager_of`. Would something along those lines make sense?

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons to be considered before storing an application specific data in AD. Pro: control of enterprise level applications, where most of AD-users use that application; ownership by dedicated and typically limited team (changes to AD usually to be done by IT/service desk), which is more secure and traceable. Contra: AD should keep data that cannot be controlled (no transparency if the data is used or not); changes to AD could take some time to propagate.

Keeping the above in view, consider

1) Use roles/membership (i.e. create roles "GeoUser US,IL,Chicago", "GeoUser US,IL", "GeoManager US,IL", etc.). This would help you to assign any number of rights to any user regardless of his primary address. Use nested AD-groups (i.e. "GeoUser US,IL" will be parent to "GeoUser US,IL,Chicago", etc.).

2) Keep loginname and date/time just to know who/when created it as well as full location (i.e. if author was in role of "GeoUser US,IL,Chicago" then store "US,IL,Chicago"). This will help you to keep location in place in case the author will change his address or will leave the company (and his account will be deleted). Authorize users based on their "Geo"-roles using a wildcard search (e.g. if user is in "GeoManager US,IL" then the WHERE clause will be WHERE level LIKE 'US,IL,%" which should find all artifacts from IL, including child locations.